# Создание и загрузка файлов без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php, файлы, асинхронность

Подскажите, нужно отослать запрос с клиента(передать название таблицы которую нужно скачать) и в зависимости от запроса создать csv файл и сразу же его скачать. Делаю так:

```
async function exportTable(data) {
    let body = {
        "method": "Export",
        "data": data,
    };

    let response = await fetch("/export", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
    
}
```

На сервере принимаю $data

```
private function Export($data){
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ". $data .");
        $query->execute();
        $queryResult = $query->fetchAll();
        
        $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($out, $queryResult);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        fclose($out);
        
    }
```

Но ничего не происходит, подскажите пожалуйста что я упустил?

Comment: Я не специалист в `php`, мои ответы могут быть только концептуальные, поэтому я просто посоветую вам как правильнее искать. Технология, которая вам нужна, называется AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML). Попробуйте поискать статьи по реализации AJAX запросов с участием ваших Frontend и Backend технологий

Comment: ajax и то как я сделал по сути одно и тоже. аякс мне нужен только для передачи строки на сервер, а вот как с сервера передать сгенерированный файл на клиент вот это вопрос

Comment: При отправке `GET` или `POST` запроса, ваше бэкенд приложение должно будет отправить ответ с response кодом. В теле этого ответа может быть нужный вам кусок `html`  или же `json` объект.

Comment: или даже файл может вернуть ажакс-запрос))